# Livewire - Cast input value

Tags: html, laravel-livewire

On Livewire i have a foreach loop to display a list of checkboxes like this:

```
@foreach($restaurantCategories as $category)
        <div class="d-flex flex-column switch-cat">
              <label class="form-check-label mb-50" for="{{$category->id}}">{{$category->id}} - {{$category->name}}</label>
                    <div class="form-check form-check-warning form-switch">
                            <input type="checkbox"
                                   class="form-check-input" value={{$category->id}}
                                   @if(array_has($restaurant_categories, $category->id)) checked @endif 
                                   wire:model="restaurant_categories"
                             />
                    </div>
         </div>
 @endforeach
```

It works fine, but when i check a checkbox the value is added to `restaurant_categories` in the component as a string and i need to add it as an integer value.

I can't cast the `$category->id` because it comes from a pivot table and it comes always as integer.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected $casts = [
    'restaurant_categories' => 'integer',
];
```

Comment: i appreciate your answer but 'restaurant_categories' is in fact an array. The solution could be:

protected $casts = [
    'restaurant_categories.*' => 'integer',
];

to force the array elements to be integer but not even that solve my problem.